# Need something earlier than a page unload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up an unload listener which sets a flag that error handlers from an ajax request check.

```
jQuery(window).unload(function() {
   unloadhappening = true;
});
```

However, the ajax request can be aborted (when the user navigates to another page) and the error handler for the ajax request invoked before the unload event is fired.

I was wondering could I get an event earlier than unload?  Obviously I could put a listener on every link to move from the page but was looking for a neater way if there is one.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Horen there is no need for my error handling logic to kick in if the user is moving away from the page.  Hence why I set the flag. My error handling logic checks that before doing anything.

Comment: @Horen: He wants to let his ajax error handlers know the reason for the abort they're detecting so that they can react appropriately

Comment: Have you tried `onbeforeunload` (though it's not supported everywhere)?

Comment: `$('a[href^=http]').click( function() { unloadhappening = true; } );` isn't that bad, is it?

Comment: @Sumurai8 - I was thinking that but something just doesn't seem right about it.  For example, what happens if the click the hyperlink but then click "STOP" on the browser.  The flag will be set as if the browser is moving to another page but it is not.

Comment: Won't the same thing happen if you attach it to the beforeunload-handler and pressing stop?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I'd imagine it would vary from browser to browser. Suffice to say that clicking a hyperlink should be earlier in the stack than the browser making a decision to unload the page.

Comment: Why doesn't your error handler just look at the error `textStatus` and if it's `abort`, assume the request was aborted, and nothing should be  done?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `onbeforeunload` or `$(window).on('beforeunload')` but return an empty string from the function to prevent the prompt about navigation.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    unloadhappening = true;
    // maybe other logic
    return '';  // or maybe return null
}
```

I haven't tested the solution to avoid the popup box in all browsers, so your milage may vary.

Comment: Try removing the return line completely. http://jsfiddle.net/Dqps3/ works on Chrome and Firefox.